# Log odds vs Log probability

Tags: logistic-regression, probability

Log-odds has a linear relationship with the independent variables, which is why log-odds equals a linear equation.

What about log of probability? How is it related to the independent variables? Is there a way to check the relationship?

Answer (score 0):

In logistic regression, it isn’t the case that the log-odds are linearly related to the features. We posit that such a relationship exists and then find the coefficients giving the best fit. That assumed linear relationship between the log-odds and the features might be an awful assumption, and that is why models like neural networks can be useful.

If you want to propose a binomial model with $\log(\mathbb E[Y\vert X])=X\beta$, feel free to do so. In fact, `R` has no trouble fitting such a model.

```
set.seed(2022)
N <- 100
x <- runif(N, 1, 2)
y <- rbinom(N, 1, 0.5) 
L <- glm(y ~ x, family = binomial(link = log))
summary(L)
```

Comment: Why do we have to make an assumption about a linear relationship between the odds of success & the independent variables? Why can't we just fit a straight line/curve through the data points as per possibility & infer coefficients from it? And why don't we take log of probability, make a similar assumption on linearity & fit a line through the data? Do we reject probability for prediction & choose odds because we need a likelihood model for parameter estimation?

Comment: @Apoorva 1) You might be interested in linear probability models. Nothing forces you to use the logistic link function.

Comment: I think this isn't getting at why log-odds is the right choice, and why a log transformation of anything is necessary. It stems from what you think the distribution of the target it is - the prediction is binomial (0/1) with some probability p. Plot this data - every y value is 0 or 1. Fitting a line doesn't make sense. You will predict < 0 or > 1 in many cases. It turns out that regressing log odds is the choice consistent with Binomial(p) distribution of the target.

Comment: @SeanOwen Or maybe a probit link fits better. Maybe a Cauchit fits better. Maybe a linear probability model with an identity link function fits better. The logistic link isn’t a law.